# How to access Gtk.Window in another class?

Tags: gtk, vala

This is how the window is constructed:

```
namespace App {

    public class Window : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
        
        private Granite.ModeSwitch stick_switch; 
        
        public Window (Gtk.Application app) {
            Object (
                application: app,
                icon_name: Constants.APP_ICON,
                resizable: false
            );
// There is more code below this
```

I want to access this window in another class. How do I do it??

When I initialize it within the constructor of another class using this: `var main_window = new App.Window ();`, an error is displayed saying that it is missing arguments.

What and how do I need to provide the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an Gtk.Application to the construcor:

```
var main_window = new App.Window(new Gtk.Application("foo.your.app.name", Gtk.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);
```

"foo.your.app.name" is the application ID.

Gtk.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE are some flags to specify the behavior of the application [link](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.ApplicationFlags.html), e.g. whether this application is a service or a launcher,....